# how to insert date and time into mysql table in the format 04 sunday, 3013

Tags: mysql

i would like to know how best to insert date and time into datebase table in the format 04 sunday, 2013. i have been trying but keeps inserting as 2013-09-16 . thanks

this is my sql code :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topic_created (subject , dateposted) VALUES ('$subject', CURDATE())";
mysql_query ($query) or die ('could not updated:'.mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're gonna shoot your foot if you keep going down this path

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query` for this? That's a woefully obsolete interface.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to not touch it. You do the date formatting when you **retrieve** the data. There is a data type for date and you should store it as such.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateposted, '...') ...
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)